# How to change encoding in Django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I get my JSON API in simple way by django rest framework my serializers.py looks like:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photo_set = PhotoSerializer(many=True)

    read_only = True

    class Meta:
    model = Article
    fields = (
        'id',
        'pub_date',
        'slug', 
        'title',
        'text',
        'youtube',
        'vimeo',
        'photoview',
        'photo_set',
        )
```

and in views.py:

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
```

I'm using textile markup language in my text field.

And If I serialize for example polish " **ę** " i got " **Ä™** " . How to change it to get "ę" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `UnicodeJSONRenderer` in your `ViewSet`:

```
from rest_framework.renderers import UnicodeJSONRenderer

class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    renderer_classes = (UnicodeJSONRenderer,)
    ...
```

Comment: Tell me how do you test the serializer and which django version is it?

Comment: In DRF 3.0, `UnicodeJSONRenderer` changed to `JSONRenderer`